# extracting number from NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

I am setting the dictionary with NSNmuber- `number` (for alarm) with :

```
#define kTimerNameKey @"kTimerNameKey"
 NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:number forKey:kTimerNameKey];
```

When i  get on the delegate a notification i have this :

```
NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.userInfo;
```

i can log it and see that its ok.

My problem is , how can i extract from `userInfo` , the number for the key ?
if i use `objectForKey:kTimerNameKey` , he doesnt know this key(its in another class)

So, extracting on the delegate the number from the userInfo is my problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just #import "YourOtherClass.h" that contains the definition for the kTimerNameKey ?

Otherwise, if you're using NSNotification to post notification, you can pass along the value of the number:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"notif_sendNumber" Object:myNumber];
```

then in your receiving class, you can go:

```
-(void)myReceivingMethod:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSNumber *receivedNumber = (NSNumber *)[notification object];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to convert this class to int, like [[userinfo objectForKey:kTimerNameKey] intValue];

Hope it works...

Answer (score 1):

```
for (NSString* key in userInfo)
{
    int value = [[userInfo objectForKey:key] intValue];
}
```

or pass key to another class.